# jQuery Removing specific text from an element

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the text "By:" from an element in my website. I want the rest of the text to remain there. How can I achieve that with jQuery? Thank you.

The HTML

```
<div id="text">By: Anonymous From Minnesota</div>
```

I want it to just be:

```
<div id="text">Anonymous From Minnesota</div>
```

Comment: remove text from what attribute of what element? Like... the current value of a text input field? Or just arbitrary text inside a div or p element?

Comment: @themerlinproject Added the HTML

Comment: @codercake Just the text inside a `div` or `p`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you wanted to find every element with "By:"  in it and remove it, you could try this:

```
$(':contains("By:")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("By:").join(""));
});
```

This removes any occurrence of "By:" in any element. If you want to target specfic type of elements, simply change `$(':contains("By:")')` to include whatever selector suits you.

Comment: This seems like what I was looking for, however, for some reason, a comma is being added randomly: http://jsfiddle.net/xSphc/

Comment: Hah! I forgot to add the separator parameter to join(). I've updated the answers with join(""). Basically what it is doing is splitting the string into an array using "By:" as the separator, then joining the array elements back into a string using nothing as the separator. Hope that helps :)

Comment: If you're interested in seing the performance of basic .split().join() verses .replace(//g, ""), you might find this interesting: http://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-regex-replace

Comment: Unfortunately when I modified the code to this: `$('table#ReviewBox tbody tr td table tbody tr td i:contains("By:")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("By:").join(""));
});` it only removed the first instance of the "By: " is there a fix for that?

Comment: If you have a fiddle with the source HTML that would hep a lot... I would assume that the selector is only matching one object, or an error is being thrown after the first replacement.

Comment: Ahh, you have multiple id attributes with the same value... jQuery (and the HTML spec) will only work with one unique id attribute. If this is changed to a class, it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/qykxJ/

Comment: @AndewOdri, this is working too well.  It is removing hyphens being used for data attributes.  Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: I like the method that keeps all the elements .html() 
It get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.
So no matter what the content of the selected element is, the .html() version will    split and join itself back together, minus the chuck you wanted removed.

Answer (score 16):

a more global solution using regular expressions. This will replace `By:` even if your string structure will change.

```js
var str = $('div').text().replace(/By:/g, '');
$('div').text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">By: Anonymous From Minnesota</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var str = $("#text").text();
$("#text").text(str.substring(3));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">By: Anonymous From Minnesota</div>
```

Using javascript's `substring` and give your div an ID to access it easily:

html:

```
<div id="text">By: Anonymous From Minnesota</div>
```

jquery:

```
var str = $("#text").text();
$("#text").text(str.substring(3));
```

You could do it in one line too:

```
$("#text").text($("#text").text().substring(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

give an unique id to div, t:

```
$('#div_id').html($('#div_id').html().substring(3));
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ChUB4/