# Obliterate (remove branding) exact HTML snippet from website NOT using javascript or CSS

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, tweak

The exact snippet, generated by software that must be removed is:

```
<p style="text-align:center;">Created by <a href="http://www.fancywebsite.com" target="_blank">FancyWebsite</a></p>
```

Perhaps PHP `str_replace()` or PHP `trim()` might work. I found these [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) and [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628324/jquery-removing-specific-text-from-an-element) examples but crash and burned after 30 minutes. Maybe regex can find occurrence and replace with `&nbsp;`?

---

If browser has J$ disabled, than visitor will see branding. This javascript snippet will not suffice, because user can "view source" and explore:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("p").each(function() {
if ($(this).html().indexOf("Created by") != -1) {
    $(this).remove();
}
});
</script>
```

Wishing you good health, wealth and wisdom in 2017 - happy new year from me to you! GLHF

Comment: Bound to be a breach of terms

Comment: OOoO my gosh, I didn't even think of that. Thanks for your input. Maybe we'll get another (4) votes to close this question or I'll edit my question to be sneeky on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

with just a minor change apply this code.

```
$("p").each(function() {
if ($(this).html().indexOf("Created by") !== -1) {
    $(this).remove();
}
});
```

And let me know if any thing else needed. Thanks

Comment: Might you know of a non-J$ solution? The posted script above works but you can still view source and find code. I wish to completely remove and delete. I just tested your code, that too works! Thanks!!!

Comment: unfortunately, CSS3 has removed contains element so you can't use it any more by CSS ...