# Removing text from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created two buttons. One adds a information from an input and the other one removes the information of the input if it exists within the list.

```
<div id = inputArea>

<button id= "add">Add</button><input type="text" name="add"></input>

<button id= "remove">Remove</button><input type="text" name="remove"></input>

</div>
<div id= "box"></div>
```

I mannaged to write the Jquery for add, but not the remove:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
var toAdd = $('input[name=add]').val();
$('#box').append("<p>" +toAdd+ "</p>");
});

$('#remove').click(function(){
var checkRemove = $('input[name=remove]').val();
(......)
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Removing specific text from an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628324/jquery-removing-specific-text-from-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter out using custom condition.

```
$('#remove').click(function(){
  var checkRemove = $('input[name=remove]').val();
  $('#box p').filter(function(){
    return $(this).html() == checkRemove;
  }).remove();
});
```

```js
$('#add').click(function() {
  var toAdd = $('input[name=add]').val();
  $('#box').append("<p>" + toAdd + "</p>");
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
  var checkRemove = $('input[name=remove]').val();
  $('#box p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() == checkRemove;
  }).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=inputArea>

  <button id="add">Add</button>
  <input type="text" name="add">

  <button id="remove">Remove</button>
  <input type="text" name="remove">

</div>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace function to remove the selected word

```
$('#add').click(function(){
var toAdd = $('input[name=add]').val();
$('#box').append("<p>" +toAdd+ "</p>");
});

$('#remove').click(function(){
var checkRemove = $('input[name=remove]').val();
var html =$('#box').html();

var res = html.replace("<p>" +checkRemove+ "</p>","");
$('#box').html(res);
});
```